# Report on Custom Object / Report Builder

Tags: reporting

I am trying to write a report on a custom object. I used the report builder, but when I select the data source, it is not possible to only select that custom object. I was wondering whether that is possible.

The other thing I am trying to do is to filter my results by the date field. So, my custom object has a date field, and I want to display all instances that are within 2 weeks of today. Again, it is not obvious to me how I can do this in the report builder as I can only select a specific date range.

Can I build reports (for dashboards) in a different way? And if not, is it somehow possible to meet my requirements using the report builder?
Tia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the custom object a child object? I believe the reports that get created automagically on those include the master object, but you should be able to create a custom report for just that report type.

In the report criteria you should be able to add the date to your filter criteria and set the date equals last 14 days.